# Decide on class to be balanced when using SMOTE

Tags: python, machine-learning, multiclass-classification

I am using SMOTE (imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE) to solve a multiclass classification problem, where some of the classes are highly imbalanced. Currently I have created a loop that will over-sample the classes with fewest observations through some iterations. The library will by default take the class with the fewest samples and over-sample it, but I would like to decide which class I want to oversample. I don't see how the library supports this option - any ideas?

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(rawdata)
X = df.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df.iloc[:, -1]

for x in range(1,3):
    print("Run Number:", x)
    print(X.shape)

    print('Original dataset shape {}'.format(Counter(y)))

    sm = SMOTE(ratio=0.5, random_state=42, k_neighbors=3)
    X, y = sm.fit_sample(X, y)

    print('Resampled dataset shape {}'.format(Counter(y)))
```